# Upload image file to cache on Pyramid

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyramid

I have a python web project based on [Pyramid](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.9-branch/). I have a confusion in deciding to use which tools I have to use to enable image uploading. I used pyramid_storage(https://github.com/danjac/pyramid_storage) to handle the image uploading before, but I haven't figured how to expire the uploaded file.

Comment: expire the uploaded file? what do you mean by this statement

Comment: @harshil9968 to make it vanished :v given a specific time